# Integration Area Between Graph

Tags: integration

Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants. It is known that the line $y=x$ is tangent to $f(x)$ when $x=4$ and the area bounded by $y=x$, $y=f(x)$ and the $y$-axis is 8. Find $f(x)$.

I need to solve for $a, b, c$ that mean I need 3 equations.
I founded 2 using the equation of the tangent.

$f'(x) = 2ax+b$

$f'(4)= 1$

$8a + b =1$ ...(1)

$\frac{y-4}{x-4} = 1$ (Derived from tangent)

$f(4) = 4$

$16a+4b+c=4$ ...(2)

I know I should use the information of the area to find the last equation, but I don't know how.

Comment: What do you know about integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have the equations
$$8a+b=1$$
$$16a+4b+c=4$$
further we have
$$\int_{0}^4 ax^2+bx+c-xdx=8$$
and from here we get
$$\frac{64}{3}a+8b+4c-8=8$$
can you finish?
in the other case, the parabola is upwards you have
$$\int_{0}^4x-(ax^2+bx+c)dx=8$$

Comment: You are missing the case where the graph is a parabola that opens upward. And since he says he doesn't know how to use the area part, I'm pretty sure your integration doesn't make a lot of sense to him without an explanation.

Comment: yes i have wrote "can you finish"

Comment: the OP must know if he/she need further assistance

Comment: Yeah that's very true, I'm reading too much into his question.

Comment: Tho it's not really about further assistance, you just gave him the next step without letting him think for himself about the concept of integration.

Comment: ok i will write down the next case

Answer (score 0):

Tangent line at $x=4$:
$$y=(16a+4b+c)+(8a+b)(x-4)=x\Rightarrow \begin{cases} \ \ \ \ \ 8a+b=1 \\ -16a+c=0 \end{cases}.$$

Thus, $f(x)=ax^2+(1-8a)x+16a.$ The parabola can have branches up or down so that the line $y=x$ touches at $x=4$.

Case 1:
$$\int_0^4 \left(f(x)-x\right)dx=8 \Rightarrow \left(a\frac{x^3}{3}-8a\frac{x^2}{2}+16ax\right) \bigg |_0^4 =8 \Rightarrow $$
$$a(\frac{64}{3}-64+64)=8 \Rightarrow a=\frac38.$$
Hence, $b=1-8a=-2; c=16a=6$.

Case 2:
$$\int_0^4 \left(x-f(x)\right)dx=8 \Rightarrow \left(-a\frac{x^3}{3}+8a\frac{x^2}{2}-16ax\right) \bigg |_0^4 =8 \Rightarrow $$
$$-a(\frac{64}{3}-64+64)=8 \Rightarrow a=-\frac38.$$
Hence, $b=1-8a=4; c=16a=-6$.